# OrderBy hasMany laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Resulta que tengo una tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en donde al lado del nombre de la columna tengo las flechas para hacer el ordenamiento por columna, y tengo un problema con la columna Role, Yap_count y Votes porque son relaciones y una de ellas esta mal hecha (estoy refactorizando el proyecto)

Cuando se hace click sobre cualquier nombre para order por columna, se llama a un método que realiza lo siguiente y aca se puede observar la relacion que mencione que esta mal hasMany-> role.role en vez de belongToMany -> roles:

```
$users = User::with('role.role')->with('comments');

  if (!empty($filters)) {
        $users->sorting($sorting);
  }
```

y el metodo sorting se llama al modelo usuarios y realiza:

```
 return $query->orderBy($sorting['field'], $sorting['direction']);
```

Pero esto claramente no funciona con las columnas de las relaciones, yo para ordenar esas columnas tengo estas condiciones

1. Para el caso de roles intente hacer esto y no anda:

   ```
   return $query->with(['role.role' => function ($q) use ($sorting) {
               $q->orderBy('name', $sorting['direction']);
           }]);
   ```

   2. Para Yap_count es `$users->withCount('comments')` no se como ordenar por withCount
2. Para votes tambien es sobre la tabla comments pero es una suma de las columnas up_votes y end_votes

   ```
   $query->whereHas('comments', function ($q) use ($operation, $votes) {
               $q->havingRaw("sum(up_votes + down_votes) $operation $votes");
           }, '>', 0)
   ```

Comment: Se podría hacerlo con `join`s, por [ejemplo](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/order-by-on-relationship) o dejar que eloquent lo haga, por [ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38741988/7498116). Pero también evaluaría el costo de ordenar por datos de relaciones en el backend, comparado con ordenar la tabla por columna en el frontend. Si los datos son los mismos, con un poco de js ahorras consultas a BD e idas y vueltas de la misma información. Podes dejar los filtros para los casos en que los datos cambian, por ej From|To|email|etc.